# Twilio SMS with URL to Google Fi Subscriber

Tags: sms, twilio

I built an app that sends SMS messages with a URL to a list of users. When sending to Google Fi phones.

the message is "Your Weekly Report is now available! Log in to check it out: [URL]".

This message sends successfully with the URL in it to phones on AT&T, Verizon, and other carriers, but not to Google Fi.

This message sends successfully to Fi if I remove the link from the message, so I know the code is good.

I have reached out to Fi and they were not at all helpful.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

remove the link. Carriers are strict when sending links via SMS, more so when using standard long codes and Application to Person (A2P) traffic (vs. two people exchange SMS directly with one another).

You can try sending from a Toll Free number, to see if you have any better luck but those still experience filtering. The true solution is a carrier short code, but that involves an extensive carrier vetting process of your business and have additional costs involved.

[How Does Carrier Filtering Work?](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181848-How-Does-Carrier-Filtering-Work-)